# Solving $\int_0^{\infty}\,dk\,\exp{(-\delta^2k^2)}\,\frac{J_1(kR)}{k^2}$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I would like to understand if there is a closed formula for this integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,dk\,\exp{(-\delta^2k^2)}\,\frac{J_1(kR)}{k^2}$$

where $R,\delta>0$ and $J_1(\cdot)$ is the bessel function of first kind of order 1.

By using the series expansion of $J_1$ and the Guassian integral, I end up with this series (with a prefactor $\delta$):

$$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^l}{2^{2l+2}}\,\frac{(l-1)!}{l! (l+1)!}\,\left(\frac{R}{\delta}\right)^{2l+1}$$

Checking with Wolfram the series does converge but is it possible to find a nicer solution? Or otherwise another way to solve the integral above?

Comment: The last series can be expressed by using an incomplete $\Gamma$ function, $\Gamma\left(0,\frac{R^2}{4\delta^2}\right)$, but there is no chance of getting something nicer, unless the ratio $\frac{R}{\delta}$ equals some particular value.

Comment: Since $J_1(x) \sim \frac{x}{2}$ the integrand is $\sim \frac{1}{k}$. How could it converge then?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for the comment. Could you please expand your solution in a complete answer. I am not looking for something expressed in terms elementary function. A solution by using an incomplete gamma function might be fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Mathematica I got:

$$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{J_1(R\sqrt{x})}{x^{3/2}}\right)=\frac{|R|}{2}\left(1-2\gamma-\frac{4s}{R^2}\left(1-e^{-\frac{R^2}{4s}}\right)+\log\frac{4}{R^2}-\Gamma\left(0,\frac{R^2}{4s}\right)\right)$$
and by expanding the RHS as a series it is not difficult to check it matches your series.